# Dynamically change height of BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I'm using the `BottomSheetBehavior` from Google recently released AppCompat v23.2. The height of my bottom sheet depends on the content displayed inside of the bottom sheet (similar to the what Google does themselves in their Maps app).

It works fine with the data loaded initially, but my application changes the content displayed during runtime and when this happens the bottom sheet retains at it's old height, which either leads to unused space at the bottom or a cut of view.

Is there any way to inform the bottom sheet layout to recalculate the height used for expanded state (when height of the `ViewGroup` is set to `MATCH_HEIGHT`) or any way to manually set the required height?

---

**EDIT:** I also tried to manually call `invalidate()` on the `ViewGroup` and the parent of it but without any success.

Comment: you could do a view height set to wrap_parent and then invalidate view after your content is loaded

Comment: view height is set to wrap_parent, but my issue is that once the view is invalidated it doesn't recalculate the height of it and the bottom sheet does just stay as it was before

Comment: Looking at the code of the BottomSheetBehavior it calculates the height in the the onLayoutChild method which is called by CoordinatorLayout. Have you tried invalidating that by calling requestLayout() on it?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205226 here is reported issue with status FutureRelease. So maybe they fixed it one day.

Answer (score 39):

I had the same problem with `RelativeLayout` as my bottom sheet. The height won't be recalculated. I had to resort to setting the height by the new recalculated value and call `BottomSheetBehavior.onLayoutChild`.

This is my temporary solution:

```
coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

int accountHeight = accountTextView.getHeight();
accountTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = bottomSheet.getHeight() - accountHeight;
bottomSheet.requestLayout();
behavior.onLayoutChild(coordinatorLayout, bottomSheet, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

Comment: I'd love to see a better solution, but right now this seems the only way to do it.

Comment: for me `bottomSheet.requestLayout()` was enough after altering the view

Comment: taking back my previous comment, instant-run was fooling with me

Comment: If you get the LayoutParams first modify them and set them back then requestLayout will be called internally for you.

Comment: I'm using this in onCreateView and setPeekHeight, requestLayout, and setState aren't doing anything. Where should I be putting this code?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `BottomSheetBehavior#setPeekHeight` for that.

```
FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
BottomSheetBehavior<FrameLayout> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
behavior.setPeekHeight(newHeight);
```

This does not automatically move the bottom sheet to the peek height. You can call `BottomSheetBehavior#setState` to adjust your bottom sheet to the new peek height.

```
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
```

Comment: No, what I'm looking for is the expanded size. I'm already using the collapsed state with the peek height. However my peek size is always limited to a preview header and the expanded size depends on how much content is available. (For ex. the description of the objects.)

Comment: I'm using this in onCreateView and setPeekHeight and setState aren't doing anything. Where should I be putting this code?

Answer (score 4):

Though the issue has been resolved in >=24.0.0 support library, if for some reason you still have to use the older version, here is a workaround.

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull final View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //workaround for the bottomsheet  bug
                    bottomSheet.requestLayout();
                    bottomSheet.invalidate();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

For bottom sheet dialog fragment, read this: [Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment Expand Full Height](https://medium.com/@OguzhanAlpayli/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment-expanded-full-height-65b725c8309)

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

   BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) getDialog();

   FrameLayout bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
   BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
   behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
   behavior.setPeekHeight(0);
}
```

Comment: Big big big thank you for the solution it is working for me. Save my lot of time

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, when trying to update the peek height based on its contents, the height from a previous layout was found. This makes sense as the new layout had not taken place yet. By posting on the UI thread the layout height is calculated after the new layout, and another layout request is made to update the bottom sheet to the right height.

```
void show() {
    setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(findViewById(R.id.sheetPeek).getHeight());
            requestLayout();
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with a problem similar to yours.

Manually setting the height of the bottomSheet was the solution for me.

Having a view *viewA* that has the BottomSheetBehaviour and a custom method *modifyHeight()* that modifies the height of the view:

```
viewA?.modifyHeight()
viewA?.measure(
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                width,
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
            ),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                0,
                MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
            )
        )
val layoutParams = LayoutParams(viewA.measuredWidth, viewA.measuredHeight)
val bottomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(viewA)
layoutParams.behavior = bottomSheet
viewA.layoutParams = layoutParams
```

My layout would be something like:

```
    <com.yourpackage.ViewA
    android:id="@+id/viewA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" />
```

It is important to reuse the bottomSheetBehaviour of the old layoutParams because it contains the peekHeight and listeners you may have attached.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when I used a recyclerview inside a BottomSheet and the items changed dynamically. As @sosite has mentioned in his comment, the issue is logged and they have fixed it in the latest release.
[Issue log here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205226)

Just update your design support library to version 24.0.0 and check.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and I'm using the new AndroidX library

Answer (score 0):

I've followed @HaraldUnander advice, and it gave me an idea which has actually worked. If you run a thread (couldn't make it work with the post method as him) after the `BottomSheetBehavior.state` is set up programmatically to `STATE_COLLAPSED`, then you can already obtain the height of your views and set the `peekHeight` depending on it's content.

So first you set the `BottomSheetBehavior`:

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(routeCaptionBottomSheet).state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
```

And then you set the peekHeight dynamically:

```
thread {
    activity?.runOnUiThread {
        val dynamicHeight = yourContainerView.height
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView).peekHeight = dynamicHeight
    }
}
```

If using Java (I'm using Kotlin with Anko for threads), this could do:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int dynamicHeight = yourContainerView.getHeight();
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView).setPeekHeight(dynamicHeight);
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet helped me solve this issue where i am toggling between visibility of different views in layout and height is automatically changing for my bottom sheet.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_bottom_sheet_layout, container, false)
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_bottom_sheet_layout)

    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val castDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet = castDialog.findViewById<View?>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                }
            }

            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {}
        })
    }

    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the toggle button click listener I have implement to set pick height of bottom sheet with animation

```
FrameLayout standardBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.standardBottomSheet);

BottomSheetBehavior<FrameLayout> bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(standardBottomSheet);    

btnToggleBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new HPFM_OnSingleClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                    if (bottomSheetBehavior.getPeekHeight() == 0) {
                        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(bottomSheetBehavior, "peekHeight", 200).setDuration(300).start();
                    }
                    else {
                        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(bottomSheetBehavior, "peekHeight", 0).setDuration(300).start();
                    }
                }
            });
```