# Android Bottomsheet TextView height not adjusted on first time expanding

Tags: android, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

### TL;DR: `TextView` in `Bottomsheet` not showing wrapped multi-line text the first time `Bottomsheet` is expanded, but adjust itself after it collapsed.

So I am using the Bottomsheet from  `design-23.2.1` library.

My layout file looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    ......

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="@dimen/bottom_sheet_peek_height"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The content of the `Bottomsheet` is basically a list:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:singleLine="false" />
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is whenever the `Bottomsheet` is set to `STATE_EXPANDED` the **first time**, the `TextView` is single line and text is wrapped, and there is no ellipsis `…` at line end.

Then after it's set to `STATE_COLLAPSED`, `TextView`'s height is fine and multi-lined properly.

I know height re-layout happened after set to `STATE_COLLAPSED` because I slide it from collapse and the multi-line is already there.

A work around is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685681/dynamically-change-height-of-bottomsheetbehavior/35804525#35804525). I followed it and added this:

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.onLayoutChild(coordinatorLayout,
                                            bottomSheetView,
                                            ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
        }
    }
    ........
}
```

It did actually make the height re-adjust when `Bottomsheet` is expanded the first time. However it occurred abruptly right after the expanding animation is done.

Is there any way to adjust the height ahead of the expanding animation just like how Google Map does?

**Update**

I found that this issue is because I have set `Bottomsheet` to `STATE_COLLAPSED` before it was expanded. If that was not set then the problem is gone and height is adjusted properly the first time.

Now my question is: why set it to `STATE_COLLAPSED` before expanding will cause that issue?

Comment: Have you tried it with the latest version (24.0.0 as of this time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to design library 24.0.0, the issue cannot be reproduced anymore.

Thanks for the efforts from the Android team to make our life easier and easier.

Answer (score 1):

if for some reason you still have to use old support library, here is the workaround for this.

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull final View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            bottomSheet.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //workaround for the bottomsheet  bug
                    bottomSheet.requestLayout();
                    bottomSheet.invalidate();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
```