# Android BottomSheet expand to bottom of another view

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-bottomsheetdialog

I'm trying to make this bottom sheet only expand to the bottom of another view but haven't been able to figure it out. I'd like the `locations_list_sheet` to expand to the bottom of `view1`.

I've tried setting the offset, `bottomSheet.setExpandedOffset(48)` but no luck with that. I've also tried setting a margin to the top of the bottom sheet layout, but that didn't look right either.

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/map_content"
            layout="@layout/content_locations_stoneco" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/locations_list_content"
            layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_locations" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

[image: Layout]

Comment: A picture of what you want would be better ... to find quick solution

Comment: try setting   `app:behavior_peekHeight="48dp"` / use `bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(48)`  as mentioned here -https://stackoverflow.com/a/35696248/6763544

Comment: @PraveenSP added photo. I'd like the bottom sheet to expand to the bottom of the green bar at the top of the layout. Currently it expands to full screen, over top of the green bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know which particular layout you are using as bottom sheet I think it must be in one of those included layouts...

add an attribute `android:translationY="48dp"` for the bottom sheet layout

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/botto_sheet"
            android:translationY="48dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"          
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

What it does is basically it will push the view to down... just like margin but kinda different.

> Note:  I don't know whether it's the correct way to do this but it does
>   the job ...Suggestions are always welcome

BTW you can add top margin also both will work

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) could help you achieve what you want!

Example from site:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Main Content"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Trying native solutions ( without external libraries ) is preferred.

Comment: OK it might help somebody else who is looking to expand from bottom. I have used it in one of my older projects...